# Deprecated notice from included block in html.twig

Tags: twig, symfony-2.3

Im getting a deprecation notice in my base twig file, but there is no 'content' block in there. Its included somewhere, but i cant find it.

```
DEPRECATED - Silent display of undefined block "content" in template "CoreBundle::base_layout.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.29 and will throw an exception in 2.0. Use the "block('content') is defined" expression to test for block existence.
```

I cant find how to debug this. I'm not getting any info from the profiler.
Is there any way to get the actual twig template to throw this error?

Comment: Never had this depreciation. You could have a block content in your template doing a `parent()` call? What happens if you creatr a `content` block in your base?

Comment: @goto I created a block and the warning went away. I'm confused.